# How do I cause gradle command-line builds to install multidex from a clean build?

Tags: android, command-line, gradle, android-multidex

I'm having issues trying to do a command line build of our Android project from a clean build (for Jenkins CI). If I open the project in Android Studio and run `Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files`, I can subsequently build from the command line. However if I try to run `./gradlew build` from the command line without first opening the project in Android Studio, I receive the following build failure:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':Redacted'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':Redacted:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.0/multidex-1.0.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.0/multidex-1.0.0.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.0/multidex-1.0.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.0/multidex-1.0.0.jar
         http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.0/multidex-1.0.0.pom
         http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.0/multidex-1.0.0.jar
     Required by:
         RedactedAndroid:Redacted:unspecified
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/
         http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml
         http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/com/android/support/support-v4/
     Required by:
         RedactedAndroid:Redacted:unspecified
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
         http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
         http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
     Required by:
         RedactedAndroid:Redacted:unspecified
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5+.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/maven-metadata.xml
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/maven-metadata.xml
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services/
         http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/com/google/android/gms/play-services/maven-metadata.xml
         http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/com/google/android/gms/play-services/
     Required by:
         RedactedAndroid:Redacted:unspecified
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:support-v4:[21,22).
     Required by:
         RedactedAndroid:Redacted:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+.
     Required by:
         RedactedAndroid:Redacted:unspecified > com.uservoice:uservoice-android-sdk:1.2.2
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:21..
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/21./support-v4-21..pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/21./support-v4-21..jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/21./support-v4-21..pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/21./support-v4-21..jar
         http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/com/android/support/support-v4/21./support-v4-21..pom
         http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/com/android/support/support-v4/21./support-v4-21..jar
     Required by:
         RedactedAndroid:Redacted:unspecified > com.uservoice:uservoice-android-sdk:1.2.2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

To my knowledge, I have all the proper dependencies specified in my Gradle scripts:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

And my app-level Gradle script:

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    ...
}

android {
...
```

Also, some of the contents of .gitignore:

```
# Android Studio and Gradle
build/
local.properties
.gradle
gradle-app.setting
*.iml
.idea/
*.ipr
*.iws
out/
.idea_modules/
```

Why can't multidex be found from a clean command line build and how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio and my command-line build were using different Android SDK installations. The one I was using on the command line didn't have some of the required Extras packages installed. Once I installed them, the build works fine.